# Error: No Result Found

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, dropdown

I tried to make an auto-submit dropdown list base on **status**, but when I put it in my repository, the page has ***nothing displayed(no result found)*** even when I tried to select from the dropdown list, it's not working at all!

Before I add this auto-submit dropdown, the page works fine not until I add the dropdown list.
I don't know where I can find the problem. Please, need some help here!

My select statement:

```
 <select  class="form-control select2" name="status" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
   <option name="status"
        {% if app.request.get('status') == '1' and app.request.get('status') == '2' and app.request.get('status') == '3'
        %}
        selected="selected"
        {% endif %} value=""> All
  </option>
  <option name="status"
        {% if app.request.get('status') == '1' %}
        selected="selected"
        {% endif %} value=""> File1
  </option>
  <option name="status"
        {% if app.request.get('status') == '2' %}
        selected="selected"
        {% endif %} value=""> File2
  </option>
  <option name="status"
        {% if app.request.get('status') == '3' %}
        selected="selected"
        {% endif %} value=""> File3
  </option>
 </select>
```

Repository:

```
 public function getFile($status) {

                $em = $this->getEntityManager();
                $query = $em->createQuery(

                        'SELECT partial a.{names},
                        partial b.{status,sender},
                        partial c.{nametypeId, nametype}
                        FROM MatrixNameBundle:file a
                        WHERE b.status = :status')

                ->setParameter('status', "%$status%");
```

Comment: why you render the `<select>` manually ? the workaround should be based on form component http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Start fixing

```
{% if app.request.get('status') == '1'
     and app.request.get('status') == '2'
     and app.request.get('status') == '3'
%}selected="selected"{% endif %}
```

Is not possible that a value is equals to three values. 1 == 2 == 3 is not possible.

And also, ... your `<option />` has no value:

```
  <option name="status" value="">File3</option>
```

Comment: The reason is to display all the values that has "1,2 and 3" when clicking All but now you said it is not possible!. And why is that even when I put one value it does not work as well.?

Comment: I also tried to put a value as what you've said that there "has no value" but the same thing happened.

Comment: maybe you want 1 || 2 || 3. A value cannot be 1 and 2, but can be 1 or 2.

Comment: I think you need to set "all" as value

Comment: can you show me a sample code wherein more than 1 values is being selected upon clicking the option button/dropdown pleaseeee.? because I can only get one value for it :-( Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, ... you need to select "all" or "1" or "2" ar "3", right?

Comment: So, if you need "all","1","2","3", ... why your code look for "1 and 2 and 3","1","2","3"?